# Copy data from another workbook without hardcoding the file path

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and transpose data from one workbook to another. Each week the file to copy information from is updated to a new workbook. In my macro I callout "Week of 06-17-19 WGN WB A-line.xlsm".

I would like to manually open the sheet to copy the data without having to hard-code the new date.

Could I use the ActiveWorkbook function to call the new open sheet?

```
Sub copytranspose()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim Column As Integer
Dim Row As Integer
Row = 5
Column = 8

For i = 1 To 6
    Workbooks("Week of 06-17-19 WGN WB A-line.xlsm").Worksheets("WEEKLY").Cells(10, Column).Copy
    Column = Column + 2
    Workbooks("copy transpose.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row,3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Row = Row + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

You can avoid hard-coding in the date into the code by storing the date of the file you want to open in a cell. Say you have a sheet called "config" and in range "A1" you have the date "06-24-19". Assuming you have both files in the same directory you could write something like this

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Column As Integer
    Dim Row As Integer
    Row = 5
    Column = 8

    Dim currFileDate As String
    currFileDate = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("A1").Value, "mm-dd-yy") '' Get the date typed in

    Dim srcDataWB As Workbook
    '' Open the workbook automatically with the file date of A1
    Set srcDataWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Week of " & currFileDate & " WGN WB A-Line.xlsm")

    For i = 1 To 6
        srcDataWB.Worksheets("WEEKLY").Cells(10, Column).Copy
            Column = Column + 2

            '' If this is the same workbook that the code is stored
            '' I suggest switching out Workbooks("copy transpose.xlsm") for ThisWorkbook
            Workbooks("copy transpose.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Row = Row + 1
    Next i
```

## Solution 2

Alternatively, if what you really want is to just match an already opened workbook that matches the pattern of "Week of * WGN WB A-line.xlsm" then the following will work. **HOWEVER** it's not bullet-proof since you could potentially have two workbooks open that match that pattern.

```
Sub DoStuff()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Column As Integer
    Dim Row As Integer
    Row = 5
    Column = 8

    Dim srcDataWB As Workbook
    '' Get the already opened workbook that matches the pattern 'Week of * WGN WB A-line.xlsm'
    Set srcDataWB = GetSrcDataWB

    For i = 1 To 6
        srcDataWB.Worksheets("WEEKLY").Cells(10, Column).Copy
            Column = Column + 2

            '' If this is the same workbook that the code is stored
            '' I suggest switching out Workbooks("copy transpose.xlsm") for ThisWorkbook
            Workbooks("copy transpose.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Row = Row + 1
    Next i


End Sub

Function GetSrcDataWB() As Workbook
    
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim currWB As Workbook
    For Each currWB In Application.Workbooks
        If currWB.name Like "Week of * WGN WB A-line.xlsm" Then
            Set GetSrcDataWB = currWB
            Exit For '' No more need to loop
        End If
    Next
    
End Function
```